# The algebraic degree of $\tan(1^{\circ})=\tan(\pi/180)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, algebraic-number-theory, minimal-polynomials

> What is the algebraic degree of $\tan(\pi/180)$?

Every now and again, I skim through *Conjecture and Proof* by Miklos Laczkovich and attempt some of the exercises. In chapter 5, on algebraic and transcendental numbers, the bulk of the chapter is spent showing the transcendence of $e$, but the beginning page or so (the chapters are quite short) asserts that if $r$ is rational, $\cos(r \pi)$ is algebraic. (This is somewhat clear a priori by the angle-addition formulas.) This makes me buy the claim that if $r=k/n$, the degree of $\cos(r \pi)$ is $\phi(n)/2$, $n$ odd and $\phi(n)$, $n$ even (here $\phi$ is Euler's totient function).

Now $180=2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5$. By the introduction, we should expect its minimal polynomial to have degree $2\cdot 6\cdot 4=48$; a gruesome calculation bears this out. (Aside: the exercise after this one has you write $\cos(\pi/15)$ by radicals, which I did, and got its minimal poly degree $4$; then $180/15=12$ and $4\cdot 12=48$, so I buy it.) So at this point, I *could* just continue on and try to get the minimal polynomial of $\cos(\pi/180)$, although I'm not sure how that would help. The tangent is throwing me for a loop: even if I knew the minimal polynomials of $\alpha=\cos(\pi/180)$ and $\beta=\sin(\pi/180)$, I'm not sure how I would compute the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^{-1}\beta$.

Another related question: when are the minimal polynomials of $\cos(r\pi)$ and $\sin(r\pi)$ the same, or when do they have the same degree? For instance, when $r=1/30$, they have degrees $8,4$ respectively; when $r=1/15$, they have degrees $4,8$; when $r=1/12$ they are identical of degree $4$.

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimal+polynomial+tan%28%CF%80%2F180%29) gives $x^{24} $ $- 48 x^{23} $ $- 564 x^{22} $ $+ 1456 x^{21} $ $+ 21186 x^{20} $ $- 12432 x^{19} $ $- 269412 x^{18} $ $+ 17424 x^{17} $ $+ 1470447 x^{16} $ $+ 45344 x^{15} $ $- 3923304 x^{14} $ $- 51744 x^{13} $ $+ 5407388 x^{12} $ $- 51744 x^{11} $ $- 3923304 x^{10} $ $+ 45344 x^9 $ $+ 1470447 x^8 $ $+ 17424 x^7 $ $- 269412 x^6 $ $- 12432 x^5 $ $+ 21186 x^4 $ $+ 1456 x^3 $ $- 564 x^2 $ $- 48 x $ $+ 1$ for $\tan(\pi/180)$.

Comment: Sure, but I don't think that's the point. Also: why not degree $48$?

Comment: The relation $\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta-1$ might bind the degree of $\tan\theta$ to that of $\cos\theta$, perhaps differing by a factor of $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t_n=\tan(2\pi/n)$. Then
$$t_n=\frac{\zeta-\zeta^{-1}}{i(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})}\in\Bbb Q(i,\zeta)\cap\Bbb R$$
where $\zeta=\exp(2\pi i/n)$.

We are in the case $n=360$ where $4\mid n$. Let's suppose then that $4\mid n$.
For $\gcd(a,n)=1$, let $\sigma_a$ be the automorphism of $K=\Bbb Q(\zeta)$
with $\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta^a$. Then $\sigma_{-1}(t_n)=t_n$
(as $\sigma^{-1}$ is complex conjugation). For $\gcd(a,n)=1$, $a$ must be odd, and then
$$\sigma_a(t_n)=\sigma_{-a}(t_n)=(-1)^{(a-1)/2}
\frac{\zeta^a-\zeta^{-a}}{i(\zeta^a+\zeta^{-a})}=(-1)^{(a-1)/2}
\tan\frac{2\pi a}{n}.$$
This equals $t_n$ iff either $a\equiv\pm1\pmod n$ or if $a\equiv(1+n/2)\pmod n$
and $n/4$ is even. If $8\mid n$ then $t_n$ has degree $\phi(n)/4$ over $\Bbb Q$
while if $4\mid n$ but $4\nmid n$ then $t_n$ has degree $\phi(n)/2$ over $\Bbb Q$.

In the case $n=360$, $8\mid n$ and $\phi(n)=96$ so that $t_{360}$
has degree $24$ over $\Bbb Q$.